# Identifier expected and Property access must assign property or use its value errors

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Using the following code I get `Identifier expected` and `Property access must assign property or use its value` errors:

ViewState["SomeKeyValue"] 
What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Please put the code and error in the question directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `ViewState["SomeKeyValue"]` should be `ViewState("SomeKeyValue")`

Square brackets would be used for c# vb uses `()`.

Answer (score 2):

VB.Net uses `()` instead of `[]` for indexers:

```
ViewState("SomeKey") = ...
```